# Matching Excel Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Would really appreciate some help. Pretty basic problem. In column A I have SSN's, Column B I also have SSN's and in column C I have dates associated with the SSN's in Column B. The problem the 2 different SSN's columns don't match and I need them too. Problem 2: The dates in column C need to stay associated with the same socials in column b.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. If yoiu need Column B to match Column A, why not just copy Column A onto ColumnB?

Comment: Column A has to stay in the same order and they don't match. ie column b right now has thousands of records. column a only has a few hundred. So what I need is to match  A to B and keep the corresponding date associated with the SSN.

Comment: How could Column B match Column A if they have different numbers of records?

Comment: They come from 2 different data sources. I am essentially showing them together here. Column b and c are from a separate master sheet. The goal is to add the date (column c) to any records where the social matches on column a. Hope that clears it up for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly simple.

Either in a new sheet or in separate columns from your original data, create create a column that represents the same column as A or the original SSN's, this can easily be done with a simple reference formula `=A1` and autofilled down.  You can do the same for the second column that is a copy of the first SSN.

For the third column just use a simple `INDEX`and `MATCH`formula like this:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(E1,B:B,0))
```

This formula I have the new data in Columns `E-G` with this formula in column G.

What this formula is doing is looking for the value of E1 within column B (looking for the value of the first SSN within the span of the column B).  It will then grab the date value from column C associated with the found value in B.  This will *not* work if multiple of the same SSN's are found within column B.

Note: You have to set the formatting of the formula cell as a `Date`